# Flaky SQLite implementation- how to improve?

Tags: android, sqlite

My app relies heavily on a database, which when the app is first opened *should* copy itself from the `/assets/` folder to the database store. However, it seems to be incredibly temperamental: for example I have almost the exact same code in my free and paid versions yet one is currently working and the other isn't.

Would you guys please mind having a look at my code and seeing what is up/can be improved? My `SQLiteOpenHelper` can be found [here](http://www.espiandev.co.uk/DatabaseHelper.html) and the `onCreate()` method of my `DataProvider` is below:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreate() {

    dh = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
    try {

        dh.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
    try {

        dh.openDataBase();

    } catch (SQLiteException ex) {

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "The database could not be copied\n" + ex.getMessage(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    return true;

}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

After having a go with the emulator, I know that the database exists, but for some reason it just doesn't want to read it...

Comment: If it helps, the error I'm currently getting is that queries to the db fail because the tables cannot be found. Don't know whether the tables exist or not, although I don't get errors saying that can't be copied.

Comment: How big (mb) is the database?

Comment: @Farray, 60KB so pretty small

Answer (score 1):

Below is code that I've used to copy databases (not sure if it could remedy the error or not, figured an alternate approach is always worth a shot).  Otherwise, I don't see anything that's jumping out that could be causing an error.

```
void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
        FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
        FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();
        try {
           inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
        } finally {
           if (inChannel != null)
              inChannel.close();
           if (outChannel != null)
              outChannel.close();
        }
     }
```

Additional thought, why open and close the database when checking to see if it exists.  Seems you could get away with something like this:

```
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    return new File(myPath).exists();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really be hardcoding the path to the databases directory. Instead of building myPath everytime you need it try constructing in the contructor with the following code:

Instance:

```
private File myPath;
```

And in constructor:

```
myPath =  context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
```